# How do I replace the Nan values with values in my array?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I've tried different ways and referred to the source code provided but could never seemed to get the values from the array in. If I do not include the int in the for statement, I'd be getting Nan values. With the int statement, the value becomes 0.00 but it would not make sense as the floats are now of type int. Please help me see where my code had went wrong. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Years 5
#define Months 12

int main(void)
{
    int year = 0, month = 0;
    float monthlytotal = 0, yearlytotal = 0;

    printf("\aWelcome. This is a generated simple weather analysis of Aruba's weather for the last 5 years.\n");

    float rainfall[Years][Months] = {
        { 126.6, 186, 6.2, 89.8, 193.8, 162.8, 168.6, 139.2, 118.9, 181, 290.2, 292.6 },//2016
        { 197.6, 158.4, 136.2, 208.6, 190, 106, 79.6, 84.2, 124.4, 120.8, 268.6, 371.2 },//2017
        { 287, 14.8, 44.6, 61.2, 132.2, 182.6, 143.2, 121.6, 144.4, 234.4, 169.6, 172.6 },//2018
        { 63.6, 31.6, 72.2, 174.8, 69, 173.8, 12.2, 11.8, 22.8, 176.8, 137.4, 421.5 },//2019
        { 88.4, 65, 108.8, 188, 255.6, 233.8, 140.8, 103.4, 150.2, 78.8, 220.6, 253.2 }//2020
    };

    printf("Based on the data collected from WEBBA, here are the results.\n");
    printf("Year\t\t\tAmt of rain\n");

    for (year = 0, yearlytotal = 0; year < Years; year++) {
        for (month = 0, monthlytotal = 0; month < Months; month++) {
            monthlytotal += rainfall[Years][Months];
        }

        printf("%d\t\t%15.2f\n", 2016 + year, monthlytotal);
        yearlytotal += monthlytotal;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `monthlytotal += rainfall[Years][Months];` you're always adding the same value. which is out of bounds. Do you mean to use `monthlytotal += rainfall[year][month];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
monthlytotal += rainfall[Years][Months];
```

should be

```c
monthlytotal += rainfall[year][month];
```

Note that `clang`'s `-Warray-bounds` (on by default in `clang`) would have found the problem at compile time.

Note that `gcc` and `clang`'s `-fsanitize=address` would have found the problem at run time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would this problem be flagged out as a warning? I built mine multiple times and the compiler showed zero errors

Comment: Detecting at compile time the use of obviously wrong value for indexes at run time require static analysis. clang performs this, but that's unusual. But both `gcc` and `clang` have a great tool for detecting incorrect memory accesses:  The address sanitizer, enabled using `-fsanitize=address`. You should do a run of your tests with it enabled.